# Facebook app in a page: auth and error 191 on redirect_uri

Tags: api, facebook-apps, facebook-page, facebook-oauth

I'm following [this docs](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/pagetab/) to create my facebook app that work in a page, but i've some errors. I've created an index.php with:

```
$i = parse_signed_request($_POST['signed_request'], $mysecret);
if ($i['oauth_token']){ 
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
        var oauth_url = 'http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/';
        oauth_url += '?client_id=MYAPPID';
        oauth_url += '&redirect_uri=' + encodeURIComponent('http://www.facebook.com/pages/null/PAGE_ID/app_MYAPPID');
        oauth_url += '&scope=email';
        window.top.location = oauth_url;
        </script>"; 
}else{
 location.href="mypage.html";
}
```

My app's settings are:

```
Website with Facebook Login: http://mysite.com/app/
Canvas URL  : http://mysite.com/app/index.php?canvas=1
Page TAB URL: http://mysite.com/app/index.php
```

This code generate

> API Error Code: 191
>   API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application 
>   Error Message:  'Invalid redirect_uri Given URL is not permitted by the application configuration.'

I've also tried with 'http://www.facebook.com/MYPAGEALIAS/app_MYAPPID' as redirect_uri but getting same error.

If i change my redirect_uri to http://apps.facebook.com/MYAPPID/index.php (but this isn't what i want!) facebook ask me auth and all works fine with firefox (IE goes into infinite loop).

I've read anywhere and i've doing others tests but i've always an error...

Answer (score 0):

Place the Canvas URL and page tab URL as

```
http://mysite.com/app/
```

Comment: It's may be written in your httaccess file. you try to correct that one.

Comment: If you don’t want that, then have http://mysite.com/app/index.html redirect to facebook.

Comment: Is there a way to specify the full path (with filename) as page tab URL??